# What is the email validation regex used by Angular built-in email validator?

Tags: angular

We're using Angular v12 built-in email validator and we want to use the same regex pattern it uses in other places to be aligned with same email validation logic, what is the regex pattern? I couldn't find it in Angular's Github, a reference to the pattern in the source code would be great too!

Comment: It is there in angular github: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.0.3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L118 Notice when you are on angular.io in the api pages (not only validator), you can see 2 icons on top, a pen and a code icon, the code icon will take you to the source code. https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern in .ts file:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```regex
/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/
```